# Пунктуация и адреса сайтов

Tags: пунктуация

Правильно ли выделен знаками препинания адрес страницы в следующей конструкции:

> Это можно сделать, перейдя по следующей ссылке: http://site.com/blablabla – и нажав на кнопку...

И где можно почитать об общих правилах в таких ситуациях?

Comment: Где-то (наверное на artlebedev.ru) читал что, поскольку в адресной строке современных браузеров http:// добавляется автоматически, писать его не нужно, иначе складывается впечатление что его нужно вводить вручную.

Comment: Спасибо, но мой вопрос касается того, допустимо ли здесь использованы двоеточие и тире.

Comment: Поскольку я не претендовал на ответ я и написал комментарий.

Answer (score 2):

По-моему, здесь лучше написать так:

Это можно сделать, перейдя по  ссылке  http://site.com/blablabla и нажав на кнопку.

В этом случае слово "ссылка" - это приложение в препозиции.